# How to await a Task inside of a test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

In my repository's unit test project, I'm creating a cleanup method to delete all of the records that were created by tests.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
private void DeleteTestExtensions()
{
    var authorization = _extensionRepository.GetAuthorizationByTaxAccountIdAndYear(_testTaxAccountId, _testTaxAccountYear);
    var extensions =  await _extensionRepository.GetExtensionsByUserIdAsync(_testUserId);
    foreach (var extension in extensions)
    {
        try
        {
            _extensionRepository.DeleteExtension(extension.ExtensionID);
        }
    }

    _extensionRepository.DeleteAuthorization(authorization.ExtensionAuthorizationID);
}
```

The first one is synchronous and works as expected, but the second method is asynchronous and tells me `the await operator can only be used on an async method`, but whenever I hover over `GetExtensionsByUserIdAsync`, I can see (plus I know) that it's defined as

`(awaitable) Task<List<Extension>> IExtensionRepository.GetExtensionsByUserIdAsync(Guid userID)`

So why would it tell me that I can't use await when it's clearly async?

Comment: `DeleteTestExtensions` needs to be `async`. Preferably `async Task`.

Comment: Test frameworks like NUnit and XUnit already support `async` - e.g. [here](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit/)

Comment: @DanielKelley Oh you're totally right.  Thanks!  Wanna submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is actually relating to `DeleteTestExtensions` which must be marked as `async`, not `GetExtensionsByUserIdAsync`.

So your method signature would become:

```
private async Task DeleteTestExtensions()
```

Note marking the method as returning `Task` means it can in turn be awaited.